# Creating an MP4 file that is tolerant to sudden failure during encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming

I'm trying to create an mp4 file that can be played in its current state even if all the bits from the encoder don't make it to disk.  This could be due to a failure in storing the file on a network file system, or by an abrupt failure of the machine doing the encoding (for instance, a power disconnect).  I am using ffmpeg to read directly from a live video source and create the mp4 file.   However, what I have noticed is that if there is an interruption and ffmpeg cannot properly close the file at the end, then it is rendered unplayable by any player that I have tried.

The method used to simulate a failure is to store the file locally and then rsync it to a new file and try to play that.  In this way, the current state of the file at a specific point in time is used to emulate the state the file would be in should encoding be interrupted.  Another more simple way is to simply try to play the file directly as it is being encoded.  Neither of these methods is successful in playing the file.

I have tried using the `-movflags +faststart` option (I also tried it without the `+`) as this option moves the moov atom to the beginning of the video; without which the file could not be played until encoding was complete.  When I tried this option I noticed that instead of the video file being written to disks in small pieces it instead started updating in blocks of 256kB. However, the video still won't play unless and until ffmpeg properly terminates writing.  Additional research suggests that this option requires that the video file be already finished recording.

Running `ffmpeg -h full` I also see that there is a `isml` option which is supposed to be used to "create a live smooth streaming feed" but this does not do the trick either.

How can I actually make the video tolerant to incomplete recording and still playing if recording is interrupted by a failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible with a *regular* MP4 as the metadata is required to play the file, and the metadata is held in memory while the file is being constructed. Once all media has been processed, the metadata is finalized and written to disk. What `faststart` does is write this metadata to the head of the file instead of the tail. But the writing still happens at the end of the operation.

However, a *fragmented* MP4 is usable even if ffmpeg gets killed midway - *most* of the written media will be viewable.

```
ffmpeg -i input <encoding parameters> -movflags +frag_keyframe+separate_moof+omit_tfhd_offset+empty_moov out.mp4
```

Most modern players support fragmented MP4s but some may not show duration or progress status on seek bar correctly.

You can convert a fragmented MP4 to a regular MP4 by remuxing.

```
ffmpeg -i fragmented.mp4 -c copy -map 0 regular.mp4
```

Comment: This works, but it seems to write close to 200 frames before the file can first be played, and at least an additional 100 frames between updates.  Is there some way to get it to update the file more quickly?   This may not seem like a lot of frames, but it's encoding a time lapse so it actually takes close to a minute so there is still a larger window that could be lost than I would like.

Comment: Probably to do with your KF interval. Add `-g 25` for a 25 frames interval. File size will be larger.

Comment: That works... for some reason the initial write is slightly more than twice the interval I specify, but subsequently it works great. Thanks!

Comment: The space savings from defragmentation doesn't seem worth it... running it on a 144MB file only reduced the file size around 2kB.  Is this typical?  Not sure what the point is for such small savings.

Comment: Defragmentation will help with compatibility; file overhead reduction is secondary.

Comment: is there any disadvantage to using something like `-g 1` so i am guaranteed to not lose any frames?  Will this do something wonky like get rid of P/B frames or will everything be normal with just a defrag copy needed at the end?

Comment: Yes, -g 1 will get rid of P/B frames, not good for compression efficiency. You can add `-flush_packets 1` to speed up writes.

Comment: What will the effect of that be if for instance there is a power failure after the chunk has been flush but before the (e.g.) 30 frame limit is reached... will the frames < 30 still be inaccessible or will `-flush_packets 1` ensure they can be displayed?

Comment: I haven't tested this scenario but assuming ffmpeg updated and flushed the metadata with the info on the flushed frames, all written frames will be playable.