# ffmpeg hangs when camera powers off, 'q' doesn't exit

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I am using ffmpeg on Windows to record video from my 3D printer.  When the printer loses power, ffmpeg hangs and does not respond when I press q.

```
ffmpeg -i "http://ultimakersystem:8080/?action=stream" Ultimaker.mp4
```

If I press ctrl+c in this situation, ffmpeg closes uncleanly and it does not write the MOOV atom so the resulting file is unplayable.  Turning the device back on does not unfreeze ffpmeg.

What do I do?  Should I report this as a bug in ffmpeg?

[image: screen shot of ffmpeg frozen command-line]

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I'm going to use https://superuser.com/a/1530949/330159 so that if ffmpeg dies, I at least have a fragmented mp4 that is usable.  (Why is that not the default behavior!??)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MP4 container is not designed to be fault tolerated.
You may try more permissive container formats like FLV, TS, WebM, MJPEG and others.

You may try setting the `timeout` argument:

```
ffmpeg -timeout 10000000 -i "http://ultimakersystem:8080/?action=stream" Ultimaker.mp4
```

For HTTP the timeout is in microseconds.
You may also try adding `-listen 1`.
I don't know if it's going to work...

---

As "out of the box thinking" solution, you can try RTMP streaming to localhost.

Execute one FFmpeg as listener:

```
start ffmpeg -y -listen 1 -timeout 10 -f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/mystream/test -vcodec copy test.mp4
```

Execute a second FFmpeg as RTMP streamer:
Example using test pattern:

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i testsrc=duration=25000:size=192x108:rate=25 -f lavfi -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/mystream/test
```

When you terminate the streamer process, the listener process is going to be closed gracefully.

---

Example using it in a batch file:

```
start ffmpeg -y -listen 1 -timeout 10 -f flv -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/mystream/test -vcodec copy test.mp4
ffmpeg -i "http://ultimakersystem:8080/?action=stream" -f lavfi -vcodec libx264 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1:5000/mystream/test
```

Comment: The .ts file suggestion worked.  With that container, ffmpeg defaulted to MPEG-2 so I added "-c:v h264" and it worked just fine, and played in VLC just fine.  By comparison though, I prefer the solution in https://superuser.com/a/1530949/330159, where ffmpeg writes the moov atom periodically since I prefer the mp4 container.  ffmpeg had trouble keeping up when writing the .ts file for some reason.  I also found VLC streamed the .mp4 when it hit the end, but it gave-up when it hit the end of the .ts.

I didn't try the -listen option, but that's genius!  If I try it I'll post another reply.

Comment: Should I report this as an ffmpeg bug?  It shouldn't hang like that right?

Comment: It looks like a bug, but I can't say if you should report it (I never reported an FFmpeg bug). Are you using the latest version? Did you check if it's not already reported? Is it reproducible without recording video from your 3D printer? (Can you reproduce the problem using synthetic video for example?)